Постоянная ошибка из-за неудачной попытки установки pgadmin
У меня есть ошибка которая возникла в процессе попытке установить pgadmin на свой linux.
Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ oracular-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg

пошерстил гугл, но пара попыток были безуспешными. Сейчас откатывать к заводским не могу, потому что не закончил проект.
Теперь из-за этого я не могу сделать apt update потому что вылезает постоянно, вот такая ошибка

Скорее всего у Вас есть дублирующийся источник в файле. Вот тут подробнее https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156409/conflicting-values-set-for-option-signed-by-regarding-source

grep -r -E '(apt.postgresql.org.gpg|apt.postgresql.org.asc)' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* чё говорит?

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt oracular-pgdg main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.sources:Signed-By: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg
вот так ответил терминал
